# C++ Class Writing Interview Query

Tags: c++

Ran across this question today:

> write a class Tool which will have a function void type() that every
>   derived class should implement . A function Action() that every
>   derived class can override . function init() which is available to
>   only Tool and variable Name which will tell which class`s instance is
>   this object

Here is my solution (based on other solutions I've found):

```
#include <typeinfo>

  class Tool{

      public:
           string name;
           Tool() {
                 name = typeid(*this).name(); 
           };

           virtual void type() = 0; 
           virtual void Action();   

      private:
           void init();  
  };
```

Could someone double check this please?

Comment: One minor thing I noticed is that you don't include std::string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would strongly recommend making `name` field const. Also, `typeid(*this).name()` won't look nice and pretty in some compilers.
You should probably try something like:

```
class Tool {
public:
  const std::string name;
  <...>
protected:
  Tool(const char* className) : name(className) {}
private:
  <...>
}
```

BTW, do NOT expect `typeid(*this).name();` to be called for deriven object. Even virtual functions won't help, so you can't write something like `virtual const char* getMyName() = 0;`, because any kind of "virtual" behavior will not work in constructor.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest adding virtual destructor. Your polymorphic class can be used threw the pointer to the base class:

```
Tool* base = new Derived();
delete base;     // virtual destructor is required here
```

As suggested by @random-guy-from-internets, it is worth adding constructor which gets human-readable type name parameter. I'd suggest only to make it explicit:

```
class Tool {
public:
  virtual ~Tool() {}
protected:
  explicit Tool(const char* className) : name(className) {}
private:
  <...>
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use templates to know what is the derived class:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>

class ToolBase {
  public:
       std::string name;
       explicit ToolBase(const std::string& classname):name(classname){}
       virtual ~ToolBase() {}
       virtual void type() = 0; 
       virtual void Action() {}
  private:
       void init(); 
};

template <typename Child>
class Tool : public ToolBase {
  public:
       Tool():ToolBase(typeid(Child).name()){}
};
```

And you use it like this:

```
class Derived : public Tool<Derived>
{
  public:
      Derived() {}
      ~Derived() {}
      void type(){
         //implementation could call Action
         Action();
      }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work: http://codepad.org/OtKa9Aki

Just like calls to virtual functions in a constructor call the base class function, such usage of typeid also does not recognise the derived class.  You could have the `Tool` constructor take an `std::string` and assign that to `name`.

Alternatively, you could be pedantic and claim that the instance of `B` will always be an instance of `B`, and that the derived classes are simply accessing this instance when they do `d.name`.  I doubt, however, that this would be appreciated.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by have the Tool constructor take an std::string and assign it to name. The problem wants the variable name to hold the name of the class - I don't think we're allowed to pass anything into the constructor.

Comment: If you cannot pass anything to the constructor, what you are being asked to do is not possible.  As you can see, calling `typeid` does not give the desired result.